# Edit or Exclude Small igraph Modules During Plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Is it possible to exclude or edit the modules being plotted so that modules with only one node do not have a module boundary? In case below, hide the module boundary around 9 and 13.

```
set.seed(3)
g <- barabasi.game(20, m=2, directed=FALSE)
eb <- cluster_edge_betweenness(g)
plot(eb, g, layout=layout_with_fr)
```

[image: igraph plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get at this using the `mark.groups` argument to `plot.communities`.  First create the default grouping, but then eliminate the groups with only one member.

```
MG = lapply(unique(eb$membership), function(m) { which(eb$membership == m) })
MG[sapply(MG, length) == 1] = NULL
plot(eb, g, mark.groups=MG, layout=layout_with_fr)
```

[image: Small groups unmarked]